# python dataframe collect() function

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am facing very weird problem while using collect() function

```
data = df.select("node_id", "bin", "type", "jsonObj").collect()
```

JsonObj looks something like this :

```
[
 {
   "id" : 1,
   "name" : "hello"
 },
 {
   "id" : 2,
   "name" : "world"
 }
]
```

now in this when I iterate through list made by collect function and print row["jsonObj"] I get my JSON object as part of string rather than just the JSON object. like now I am getting " **'** " added to each object in array. The problem with this is when I try to write it in a file it becomes array of string rather than array of json object

```
['{
   "id" : 1,
   "name" : "hello"
 }',
 '{
   "id" : 2,
   "name" : "world"
 }'
]
```

Did anyone else face same issue? I just want to store JsonObj as it is to the file rather than as string.

| node_id | bin | type | jsonObj |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | type1 | [ { "id" : 11, "name" : "hello" }, { "id" : 12, "name" : "world" } ] |

```
root
 |-- node_id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- bin: string (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- jsonObj: array (nullable = true)
```

Comment: The dataframe probably has the jsonobj column as array of string type. If you want JSON object you'll need to cast it to array of structs using `from_json`.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to do this ?

Comment: I have added sample response in the question above

Comment: And how are you writing it to a file. Are you writing it as a csv file? Or a json file?

Comment: I am writing it to Json file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the JSON string to a struct using `from_json`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import *

df2 = df.withColumn(
    "jsonObj",
    F.from_json(
        F.col('jsonObj').cast('string'), 
        ArrayType(StructType([StructField('id', IntegerType()), StructField('name', StringType())]))
    )
)

df2.show(truncate=False)
+-------+---+-----+--------------------------+
|node_id|bin|type |jsonObj                   |
+-------+---+-----+--------------------------+
|1      |a  |type1|[[11, hello], [12, world]]|
+-------+---+-----+--------------------------+

df2.write.json('filepath')
```

which should give the output as

```
{"node_id":"1","bin":"a","type":"type1","jsonObj":[{"id":11,"name":"hello"},{"id":12,"name":"world"}]}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting the solution. However I am getting

: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
no viable alternative at input '>'(line 1, pos 28)

Comment: @A007 ... spark version problem. requires spark >= 2.4 to use transform.

Comment: Got it, is there any other alternative for spark version < 2.4 ?

Comment: Do we need any import for array and struct as well ?

because now I am getting no viable alternative at input '<

Comment: spark version is '2.2.0'